# importlib can't find module

Tags: python, python-importlib

**cat test.py**

```
from importlib import import_module

bar = import_module('bar', package='project')
```

**ls project/**

```
__init__.py  
__init__.pyc
bar.py
bar.pyc
```

**python test.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    bar = import_module('bar', package='project')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bar
```

Listing imported modules (sys.modules) doesn't show any module *project*.

I can import *bar* using the python shell.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is `test.py` relative to `project/` ?

Comment: it is in the same folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs a dot in front of bar .. :-(

```
bar = import_module('.bar', package='project')
```

Comment: Or skip passing the `package` argument and just call it as `import_module('project.bar')`, which still returns `bar` (unlike the `__import__` special function, which would return `project` after importing both `project` and `project.bar`).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [import_lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) says that

> If the name is specified in relative terms, then the package argument must be specified to the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg') will import pkg.mod).

Thus the expression can also be written as

```
bar = import_module('..bar',package='project.bar')
```